# Add "REST API Client..." menu not available

Tags: visual-studio, api, rest

I have been successfully using the Visual Studio tool for generating REST API clients for a while, but after installing the latest Visual Studio updates the option is no longer available.

I haven't found any info on how to restore the tool. Anyone knows how to restore it?

[image]

UPDATE: here is how my menu looks like
[image: No REST API menu]

Comment: I have VS 2015 with all the latest updates (not update 2 since it's RC), and I see the menu option. Are you sure it's just not hiding?  The context menu is so long, it's hard to find sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed another difference on the missing menus: the "Add New Azure Webjob project" and "Existing Project as Azure WebJob" were missing as well. So I tried **reinstalling the Azure SDK 2.8.2 and all the menu options are available again**.

I suspect that the "Cloud Explorer for Visual Studio" update I installed some days back is guilty. I didn't know that the "Add REST API client..." utility was part of the SDK (perhaps not, but reinstalling fixed the problem).

[image: REST API menu ok]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the REST API Client for your Azure Project in you fresh VS 2015 you need to install [Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET(VS 2015)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=518003) first (SDK for 2013 won't work). Close and re-launch the VS and you should get the option to add REST API Client option.

Find more information here
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/01/11/getting-started-with-azure-api-apps-and-azure-mvc-web-app-in-azure-app-service.aspx